minted 3.x is no more compatible with (inline) math?
Consider the following MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{minted}    % uncomment this line to use minted 3.x
%\usepackage{minted2}  % uncomment this line to use minted 2.9. It requires `-shell-escape`
\begin{document}
\mintinline[mathescape]{python}{$4\cdot$ 512} units

\mintinline[escapeinside=££]{python}{£\(4\cdot\)£512} units

\(4\cdot\text{512}\) units

\(4\cdot\text{\mintinline{python}{512}}\) units % comment out this line to remove error
\end{document}

Now I tried to compile it with LuaLaTeX
latexmk -interaction=nonstopmode -lualatex ./foo.tex

But compilation fails on TexLive 2024 (updated)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=200000].

Switching from minted 2024/11/10 v3.3.0 to minted2 2024/05/09 v2.9 (see comments in previous code block). Everything works! But, as reported here, this version won't receive any updates in the future, so I would prefer using the latest version.
I read that it is possible to increase pool-size to avoid this error. I'm not sure if this is a good solution and I don't want to edit my texmf.cnf unless this is not stricly necessary.
To be more sure, I tried this MWE on Overleaf. But unfortunately, Overleaf always loads minted 2023/12/18 v2.9. I don't know if it is possible to force package update in Overleaf (I don't think).

" I don't know if it is possible to force package update in Overleaf" Overleaf doesn't update packages. It only provides a new texlive version once a year.

It works with \mbox rather than \text  in the last example

https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/423

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you for this info. I don't use Overleaf and from now on I have one more reason to avoid it.

I posted a workaround in https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/423. In the \mathchoice used in \text, \stepcounter and \addtocounter only work in the first case (for \displaystyle), and are simply skipped in the remaining three cases (to make the counter operations execute only once). But minted v3.3.0 (2024/11/10) relies on the original behavior of \stepcounter to step loop counters. Therefore when \stepcounter does nothing, \mintinline doesn't work as expected.

Should be fixed with minted v3.4.0, fvextra v1.10.0, and latex2pydata v0.4.0, all released on 2024-11-17.

I have just tested minted v3.4.0 and it works! So I think it is possible to set this question as off-topic.

As you are using lualatex you can redefine \text to use a luatex primitive. But imho it would be much better to simply use e.g. \mbox{}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{minted}    % uncomment this line to use minted 3.x

\makeatletter %lualatex only!
\def\text@#1{{%
           \ifcase\mathstyle
           \hbox{{#1}}\or
           \hbox{{#1}}\or
           \hbox{{#1}}\or
           \hbox{{#1}}\or
           \hbox{{\let\f@size\sf@size\selectfont#1}}\or
           \hbox{{\let\f@size\sf@size\selectfont#1}}\or
           \hbox{{\let\f@size\ssf@size\selectfont#1}}\or
           \hbox{{\let\f@size\ssf@size\selectfont#1}}\or
           \ERROR
           \fi
           \check@mathfonts
         }}
\makeatother         
\begin{document}
\mintinline[mathescape]{python}{$4\cdot$ 512} units
%
\mintinline[escapeinside=££]{python}{£\(4\cdot\)£512} units
%
\(4\cdot\text{512}\) units

\(4\cdot\text{\mintinline{python}{512}}\) units % comment out this line to remove error
\end{document}


this is probably a minted bug though? I was just looking but don't see exactly where it's looping

@DavidCarlisle probably, but the new minted does a lot writing to files and calls to external applications and putting that inside a mathchoice looked daring ... (quite apart that even if it worked if would do it more than once).

Yes it works with a mathchoice and for \hbox as well, maybe I'll raise at the minted github

@DavidCarlisle do you know where it loops?

I decided I had looked long enough:-)  https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/423

@UlrikeFischer Thank you for your answer, but your right! @DavidCarlisle 's solution is better. Furthermore, this error also appears with pdflatex. So in this sense \mbox is more general solution.

@miticollo yes but if it were in a fraction or subscript mbox would get the wrong size, \text gets smaller in those contexts, in which case this version would work better
